# GetFields method to get enum values

Tags: .net, reflection, enums

1. I have noticed that when calling `GetFields()` on enum type, I'm getting an extra fields with type int32.  where did it come from??
2. When I call the other overload `(GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static) )`, it returns the desired fields. is that means that the enum's fields are not Public ?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<strike>Reflector</strike> [IL Spy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) can explain this.

Take a look at a decompiled enum and you will see something that looks like this:

```
.class public auto ansi sealed ConsoleApplication1.Foo
    extends [mscorlib]System.Enum
{
    // Fields
    .field public specialname rtspecialname int32 value__
    .field public static literal valuetype ConsoleApplication1.Foo Bar = int32(0)
    .field public static literal valuetype ConsoleApplication1.Foo Baz = int32(1)

} // end of class ConsoleApplication1.Foo
```

i.e. the `Foo` enum is implemented as a sealed class that wraps an `int32` called `value__` - the extra field you are seeing.

Its worth noting that it also inherits from `System.Enum` which *also* has extra (static) fields.

Comment: so the reason for the mystery field is that it inherits from System.Enum ?

Comment: @eyal Nope - the extra `int32` field is defined on the "enum class" itself and is called `value__`

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the field is the underlying value - after all, that value has to be stored *somewhere*. So an enum like this:

```
public enum Foo
{
    Bar = 0,
    Baz = 1;
}
```

is a bit like this:

```
public struct Foo
{
    public static readonly Bar = new Foo(0);
    public static readonly Baz = new Foo(1);

    private readonly int value;

    public Foo(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See "Assemblies and scoping" in the Common Language Infrastructure (CLI) standard, ECMA standard 335. I would provide a more specific location but the specifics seem to be subject to change. Go to [Ecma International](http://ecma-international.org) for the standard. See "CLS Rule 7" that says:

> The underlying type of an enum shall be a built-in CLS integer type, the name of the field shall be "value__", and that field shall be marked RTSpecialName.

That is the field, correct? I don't thoroughly understand that but at least it tries to explain what it is. It is required by the standard.